# How to calculate the difference of a result set of rows sharing a value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, pivot

With the follow result set:

```
side|timestamp_ms|sum  |
----|------------|-----|
blue|         135| 1000|
red |         135| 1100|
blue|        1943| 2500|
red |        1943| 2900|
```

How can i calculate the difference of the sums between blue and red sides that share a timestamp_ms?

Ideally the new result set should be something like:

```
timestamp_ms|diff |
------------|-----|
         135| -100|
        1943| -400|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is a `join`:

```
select tb.timestamp_ms, tb.sum - tr.sum
from t tr join
     t tb
     on tr.timestamp_ms = tb.timestamp_ms
where tr.side = 'red' and tb.side = 'blue';
```

Another method is conditional aggregation:

```
select timestamp_ms,
       (sum(t.sum) filter (where t.side = 'blue') -
        sum(t.sum) filter (where t.side = 'red')
       )
from t
group by timestamp_ms
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    timestamp_ms,
    sum(case side when 'blue' then t.sum when 'red' then -t.sum end) diff
from mytable t
group by timestamp_ms
```

This would also work if your data has more than one occurence of each `side` per `timestamp_ms`.

Side note: `sum` is a language keyword, hence not a good choice for a column name.